# How to sign a string under iOS using encrypted key?

Tags: java, python, ios, cryptography, rsa

I have keys created in Java. The private key is PKCS#8 encrypted, in PEM string.

Here is an example of using the private key with M2Crypto in Python:

```python
from M2Crypto import EVP, BIO
privpem = "-----BEGIN ENCRYPTED PRIVATE KEY-----\nMIICoTAbBgoqhkiG9w0BDAEDMA0ECFavEvdkv3fEAgEUBIICgAWvHvH6OktLiaaqo9v+X6XEuY3M\nZr465VmZWzP9nsbTqwSKQQjseiD/rWAxK7RS+V+hit5ZxlNRAUbkg0kwl8SRNX3v6q8noJtcB0OY\ndBEuNJDmWHMHh8qcnfRYc9WXPPmWdjQM2AkfZNfNOxHVlOMhancScy6P4h3Flri9VyUE8w2/zZqK\nBAd2w39V7gprCQXnnNenNuvr4p8MjsdBm8jh00o2HJzN0I6u+9s7M3qLXxwxNepptgU6Qt6eKHi6\njpsV/musVaohLhFMFAzQ87FeGvz/W8dyS9BtAKMRSuDu/QdWIJMRNKkPT0Tt1243V3tzXVXLjz0u\nm/FX6kfxL8r+eGtTr6NKTG75TJfooQzN/v08OEbmvYD/mfptmZ7uKezOGxDmgynn1Au7T/OxKFhx\nWZHpb9OFPIU0uiriUeyY9sbDVJ054zQ/Zd5+iaIjX5RsLoB4J+pfr4HuiVIZVj+Ss2rnPsOY3SjM\ntbHIFp/fLr/HODcDA5eYADRGpBIL9//Ejgzd7OqpU0mdajzZHcMTjeXfWB0cc769bFyHb3Ju1zNO\ng4gNN1H1kOMAXMF7p6r25f6v1BRS6bQyyiFz7Hs7h7JBylbBAgQJgZvv9Ea3XTMy+DIPMdepqu9M\nXazmmYJCtdLAfLBybWsfSBU5K6Pm6+Bwt6mPsuvYQBrP3h84BDRlbkntxUgaWmTB4dkmzhMS3gsY\nWmHGb1N+rn7xLoA70a3U/dUlI7lPkWBx9Sz7n8JlH3cM6jJUmUbmbAgHiyQkZ2mf6qo9qlnhOLvl\nFiG6AY+wpu4mzM6a4BiGMNG9D5rnNyD16K+p41LsliI/M5C36PKeMQbwjJKjmlmWDX0=\n-----END ENCRYPTED PRIVATE KEY-----\n"

msg = "This is a message."
privkeybio = BIO.MemoryBuffer(privpem)
privkey = EVP.load_key_bio(privkeybio) #pw: 123456
privkey.sign_init()
privkey.sign_update(msg)
print privkey.sign_final().encode('base64')
```

And here is example of how I can use the PEM (with header and footer stripped off) in Java:

```java
String msg = "This is a message.";
String privpem = "MIICoTAbBgoqhkiG9w0BDAEDMA0ECFavEvdkv3fEAgEUBIICgAWvHvH6OktLiaaqo9v+X6XEuY3M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";
byte [] privkeybytes = Base64.decode(privpem);

EncryptedPrivateKeyInfo encprivki = new EncryptedPrivateKeyInfo(privkeybytes);

Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(encprivki.getAlgName());
PBEKeySpec pbeKeySpec = new PBEKeySpec("123456".toCharArray());
SecretKeyFactory secFac = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance(encprivki.getAlgName());
Key pbeKey = secFac.generateSecret(pbeKeySpec);
AlgorithmParameters algParams = encprivki.getAlgParameters();
cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, pbeKey, algParams);
KeySpec pkcs8KeySpec = encprivki.getKeySpec(cipher);
KeyFactory kf = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
PrivateKey pk = kf.generatePrivate(pkcs8KeySpec);

Signature sig = Signature.getInstance("SHA1withRSA");
sig.initSign(pk);
sig.update(msg.getBytes("UTF8"));
byte[] signatureBytes = sig.sign();
String b = Base64.encodeBytes(signatureBytes, Base64.DO_BREAK_LINES);
System.out.println(b); // Display the string.
```

How would this be done in iOS? I have looked at the CryptoExercise, in particular the SecKeyWrapper, but there is lots going on there, and it's beyond me.

I am not personally going to be doing the iOS development, but I need some code to give to the developer to at least show more or less how to do it. The developer is more a UI type and not familiar with crypto. (Neither am I but that is a different story...)

And while we're at it, how to verify a signature against a string public key PEM? I won't put the Java and Python examples here as they are pretty straight forward.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem last week. The CommonCrypt library on iOS is very nice for symmetric key encryption, but it's just too much hassle dealing with the keyring to do simple public key things. After spending about half an hour poking at it I just included OpenSSL. [OpenSSL-Xcode](https://github.com/sjlombardo/openssl-xcode) made this trivial to set up - just drop the project and the OpenSSL tarball in, set your target to link with libssl, and you're good to go.

The OpenSSL code looks nearly the same as the M2Crypto one.

Comment: That looks promising. Any chance you could post some (pseudo) code? I know neither C nor Objective C, so despite looking at the docs and a few online examples, I'm not that close to having a "here's how to do it" example.